# Can the HDMI input of the Dell monitor U3219Q handle a 4k@60fps input signal?

Tags: monitors, hdmi, 4k

I'm search for a monitor that can handle an input signal of 4k at 60fps, over its HDMI input.

I've found the Dell Ultrasharp U3219Q that have a HDMI port. As you can see in [its online manual](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_display_projector/esuprt_display/dell-u3219q-monitor_user%27s-guide_en-us.pdf), page 14 in the table :

> Ports and connectors : 1 x DisplayPort version 1.4 (HDCP 2.2)•   1 x HDMI port version 2.0 (HDCP 2.2)

But, in page 16, again in the table :

> Electrical specifications
>
> Video input signals : HDMI 2.0*/DisplayPort 1.4**, 600 mV for each differential line, 100 ohm input impedance per differential pair
>
> ...
>
> - Not supporting HDMI 2.0 optional specification, including HDMI Ethernet Channel (HEC), Audio Return Channel (ARC), standard for 3D format and resolutions, and standard for 4K digital cinema resolution.
>     ** HDR is supported, but HBR3 is not supported; DP 1.2 is supported.

So, this is an HDMI 2.0 input port, but it doesn't support HDMI 2.0 specification ? What am I supposed to understand there ?

Does anyone have this monitor and can attest if this port allows or not a 4k@60 input signal ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the HDMI input of the Dell monitor U3219Q handle a 4k@60fps input signal?

Yes.

The footnotes on that page of the manual can be rephrased like this:

> Supports HDMI 2.0, but without optional specifications ... such as 4K digital *cinema* resolution (4096 x 2160).

If you look at the page right above "Electrical Specifications" you can see that the monitor does support `3840 x 2160 @ 60hz` as long as the video device supports HDMI 2.0.

---

And another note on 4K terminology:

`3840 x 2160` and `4096 x 2160` are both casually called "4K" but to avoid ambiguity the former is referred to as "UHD". The Digital Cinema Initiatives (DCI) have used "4K" for their `4096 x 2160` resolution too, so it is more specific to refer to that as "DCI 4K" or "Cinematic 4K", which is what Dell has done in your manual.